# Загадочный Sanic Redis

Tags: redis, asyncio, sanic

Подключил себе sanic-redis

```
app = Sanic()
redis = SanicRedis(app)   

app.config.update(
    {
        'REDIS': {
            'address': ('0.0.0.0', 6379),
            # 'db': 0,
            # 'password': 'password',
            # 'ssl': None,
            # 'encoding': None,
            'minsize': 1,
            'maxsize': 10
        }
    }
)
```

и увеличиваю на каждый запрос счетчик ошибок или успехов, но с каждым запросом ловлю вот такую ошибку:

```
Connection <RedisConnection [db:0]> has pending commands, closing it.
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ConnectionForcedCloseError()>
aioredis.errors.ConnectionForcedCloseError
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ConnectionForcedCloseError()>
aioredis.errors.ConnectionForcedCloseError
```

При этом все нормально работает, не сыпется, в общем, все хорошо.

Вопрос: как открыть незакрывающееся соединение с редисом?

```
async def count_statistic():
    await redis_client.incr_success_and_all_count_in_redis()
    now = time.time()
    last_timestamp = await redis_client.get_timestamp_from_redis()
    redis_client.time_to_response = now - redis_client.time_start_request
    await redis_client.incr_sum_time_response_in_redis(redis_client.time_to_response)
    await redis_client.put_timestamp_to_redis(now)
    ttl = await redis.conn.pttl('average_stats')
    if (now - last_timestamp < 60):
        try:
            all_count, sum_time_response = await redis_client.get_for_statistic()

            first_average = sum_time_response / all_count
        except TypeError:
            return 0

        with await redis.conn as r:
            r.hset(redis_client.key, 'first_average', first_average)
            r.hset('average_stats', 'average_per_minute', first_average)
        await redis.conn.expire('average_stats', 120)
    else:
        await redis_client.drop_data()
```

Comment: Если вопрос спустя четыре месяца ещё актуален, то покажите хоть, как именно вы работаете со счётчиками

Comment: @andreymal О, спасибо за реакцию! сейчас покажу (обновлю вопрос)

Comment: Предположу, что таки забыли await возле hset

Comment: @andreymal а разве того, что я вызываю with await недостаточно?

Comment: Недостаточно, with await просто корректно закроет соединение после выхода из блока with (если я правильно понимаю), а забытые корутины никто запускать не будет, они так и останутся забытыми

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) блестяще справился с вопросом в [комментриии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/951081/#comment1700430_951081). Не хватало `await` перед `hset`.

Снова причиной всему была невнимательность.